# Updating VBA code from Microsoift Office 32 bit to Microsoft Office 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

What changes need to be made to this coding (VBA in Office/EXCEL 32 bit) to work in Office/EXCEL 64 bit?  I have been researching stackoverflow for answers.

```
Public Function FindInArray(a As Variant, tofind As Variant) As Integer
'Returns -1 if not found or position in array if found
Dim i As Integer

FindInArray = -1

If Not IsArrayEmpty(a) Then
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If a(i) = tofind Then
            FindInArray = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If

End Function
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that a change needs to be made?

Comment: This one doesn't work in either version. There is `IsArray` and there is `IsEmpty` but there is no `IsArrayEmpty` in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

### Index of the First Matching Value in an Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NumMatchTEST()
    
    Dim Arr() As Variant: Arr = VBA.Array(CVErr(xlErrNA), Date, 1, 2, "Yes")
    Debug.Print NumMatch(Arr, 2) ' 3 since 'Arr' is zero-based
    Debug.Print NumMatch(Arr, "Not") ' -1 since not found
    
    ReDim Arr(1 To 4): Arr(4) = "New"
    Debug.Print NumMatch(Arr, "New") ' 4 since 'Arr' is one-based
    Debug.Print NumMatch(Arr, Nothing) ' -1 since an error occurred

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the index of the first matching value ('FindValue')
'               in an array ('Arr').
' Remarks:      It will work correctly for a 1D array
'               and for a single-column 2D array, with a lower limit >= 0.
'               It returns '-1' if no match or if an error occurs.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function NumMatch(Arr() As Variant, ByVal FindValue As Variant) As Long
    NumMatch = -1
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ArrIndex As Variant: ArrIndex = Application.Match(FindValue, Arr, 0)
    If IsNumeric(ArrIndex) Then NumMatch = ArrIndex + LBound(Arr) - 1

ProcExit: Exit Function
ClearError: Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to be changed in this code to work in 64bit Excel.

The official Microsoft documentation "[Compatibility between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office)" can easily be discovered with a quick web search.

> VBA 7 replaces the VBA code base in Office 2007 and earlier versions.
> VBA 7 is available in both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office.
> It provides two conditional compilation constants:
>
> VBA7 - Helps ensure the backward compatibility of your code by testing
> whether your application is using VBA 7 or the previous version of
> VBA.
>
> Win64 Tests whether code is running as 32-bit or 64-bit.
>
> With certain exceptions, the macros in a document that work in the
> 32-bit version of the application also work in the 64-bit version.